# Best way to export and import all Apigee Edge objects related to an org?

Tags: apigee

Are there scripts for exporting and importing all Apigee Edge objects, such as developers, users, apps, caches, key value maps, etc?

To clarify, it would be nice to have non-runtime objects as a priority vs. the runtime data contained within.  E.g., the current content of caches are not as critical as just having the cache object available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is work planned to provide a tool that will export/import provisional data (such as apps, developer, products).  Other aspects of an org's configuration require access to the production Cassandra database, which cannot be given out publicly.  We have a provisional tool for in-house use that we are currently hardening.  If the consumer tool (when it is available) doesn't provide all of the backup support you need, you will need to log a support ticket for them to run the in-house tool.

Comment: I'm also curious about this, what if you build out a backend for a client and then they later want to move it elsewhere?

Answer (score 4):

I have released a tool that can be used to retrieve Apigee organization settings. This tool has been in use internally at Apigee for some time, but this is the first time it has been released to the public. It uses the Apigee management API to pull configuration data, and that data to be pulled is configurable. The data is stored in a hierarchical directory structure, which can be archived, explored, or used to compare organizations. It can be used with both the Apigee Edge cloud and on-prem offerings.

A few caveats:

1. This tool does not retrieve all data from an organization. For example, it does not retrieve API proxies. Use the Apigee management UI or management API to retrieve API proxies.
2. The tool is composed of a few bash scripts. It has been successfully run on Linux and Mac OS X.
3. The tool does not write data back into the organization, although the files it retrieves can often be POSTed back to the organization using the management API.
4. This tool is released as-is. It is not officially supported by Apigee.

Find the tool at the api-platform samples site (https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples) in the tools/org-snapshot directory.

Comment: Very good work. Thanks Mike - tool helped me a lot in taking snapshot in a critical time.

Answer (score 0):

There are scripts for importing a set of objects (developers, apps, API products) that work with the sample proxies that you can find on GitHub:

https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/setup

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.  I'm looking more for a comprehensive solution that cover all objects on both export and import.

Comment: In addition to the tool described above, you can also use the APIs. There are some sample scripts here: http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/deploy-api-proxies-using-management-api, and the specific resources exposed by the API can be found here:  http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/api-reference-getting-started. These include caches, tokens, virtual hosts, environments, etc. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  This question is more to the point of the existence of a script, not so much the ability to export/import .  Many clients are looking for a vetted script they can use, and since many clients have the same need, ideally we would have a set of scripts for everyone to share.

Answer (score -1):

For Perl programmers: see also Apigee::Edge on CPAN