# Is it possible to change organization name in Apigee?

Tags: apigee

I chose an organization name which I want to change now, when I signup my account. I couldn't find a way to change it in the admin portal. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no easy way to the change Org name.  If you haven't used the Org much, recreate it under the new name (e.g., using setup-org.sh) and delete the old one. Otherwise, some tools will be out soon to help you transfer your Org to a new Org.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did.

Comment: Glad to help.  BTW, you probably already did this, but to delete an Org, you can modify <unzipped OPDK dir>/test/test1-mp-cleanup.sh and the API calls within.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think it is possible to change an org name once it is created. However you might want to check it with apigee support - http://apigee.com/about/support/request-support

Comment: If you cannot manage to change your org name any how and wish to create a new org anyway, follow this thread where you can migrate all your org metadata (products,apis,developers etc) from one org to another.

Comment: Sorry missed to pass it last time. Here you go - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125383/best-way-to-export-and-import-all-apigee-edge-objects-related-to-an-org

Comment: I assume your solution should work, but I actually created a new org instead. Thanks anyway.